# Is inheritance a viable solution to pass a set of model parameters to different classes?

Tags: c++, parameters, multiple-inheritance

I present my problem in the form of two questions.

First, I have a set of parameters which are obtained from a parameter file and need to be used in different classes of the model. I did this by creating a parsing class (let's call it parse_class) that reads the file and stores the parameters (with tag and value) using a hash table. Then, I use this class as a parent class for other classes that I need to use the parameters. Is this a good practice?

Second, using the above-mentioned method, I inherited "parse_class" in two classes, one of which is derived from another. In other words:

```
class parse_class {
    static T parameters;
};
class A: public parse_class{}
class B: public A, public parse_class{}
```

The reason I inherited again from parse_class in class B is that without it, the parameters member of parse_class is not recognized in class B (which is probably the subject of another question). This leads to `warning: direct base "parse_clase" inaccessible in "class B" due to ambiguity.` Any idea how to improve this?

Comment: The phrase "parameters are not recognized"  does not convey any useful information whatsoever. Please follow the instructions for creating a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

At the first question, the answer is no. 
You should use containment instead of inheritance. 
Inheritance is a relationship of type "is a". By using it as the base of your hierarchy you are stating that every class is a parameter file parser.

Comment: I understand your point from the coding point of view but this approach makes my model way more efficient. Containment is not something I would rather go for this case.

Comment: More efficient in terms of what? Certainly not speed. And from the coding point of view, it is simply bad design.

Comment: the reason is I use the values of these parameters to do some math calculations in the bodies of other classes and if I use confinement, I have to modify all those equations. From the design perspective, you are completely right

Answer (score 1):

I think inheritance is a bad idea as ***@Matei Florescu*** mentioned. And you also seem to not have really understood what `static` does.

Some hints:

- You don't need to inherits a class to access its public static members.
- You don't need an instance of the class to access its public static members
- A static member of a class is unique (in other words, shared by everyone)

Knowing that, based on your code, you could write:

*.h*:

```
class ParamsParser
{
    public:
        static T parameters; // I assumed T is defined
        static void loadParameters(); // A method to load the parameters and store them into the above member "parameters"
};
```

*.cpp*:

```
T ParamsParser::parameters = {/*some default intialization*/};

void ParamsParser::loadParameters()
{
    //parse your file and store data in ParamsParser::parameters
}
```

Note that you have to call `ParamsParser::loadParameters()` at the beginning of your program in order to get the desired parameters file loaded once and for all.

Then every time you need these data for your calculations (in `A` or `B` or whatever), you just have to access the parameters like this `ParamsParser::parameters`.

Comment: I actually understand what is a static member and how to deal with it. I tried to simplify my problem with the given description but as it appears, I have failed to convey the problem properly. But I upvoted you for your admirable effort in helping

Comment: @JalilNourisa Ah, it seems that I didn't understand what is your problem then, I'm sorry.